# Integrating BlogEngine with MVC 3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, blogengine.net

I know it is possible to integrate traditional ASP .NET into an MVC application as I have done the same when I've needed to use Microsoft Report Viewer.

I've been looking for a decent engine but I don't want to risk using any fledgling ones when more established ones already exist (unless anyone knows any really solid MVC 3 Razor blogging engines).

I was just wondering if anyone has tried to integrate it with MVC before and and how well it had come off, I don't wan't to dive in and spend days on it if it's going to be a mistake to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen, [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) has a good Blogging Engine and is well supported. I have only used it as a complete CMS solution though and not tried to separate out the Blogging engine from it, but I am sure it would be possible.

Comment: My worry with orchard was that it is still relatively new, but if you've had good experience with it then I may give it a go. Thanks

Comment: It is relatively new, but i think that it has a good future as it is well supported and from what I can find, it is the biggest MVC 3 CMS. I could be wrong.